# NTFS junction from Windows Store Gears 5 pointing to kernel device

Tags: powershell, ntfs, windows-store-app, junction

I just installed the new Gears 5 game from Windows Store and I can't figure out where it's installed so that I whitelist it in the firewall.

```
PS C:\Program Files\WindowsApps> Get-Item .\Microsoft.HalifaxBaseGame_1.1.56.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe | Format-List *


PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.HalifaxBaseGame_1.1.56.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
PSChildName       : Microsoft.HalifaxBaseGame_1.1.56.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : True
Mode              : d----l
BaseName          : Microsoft.HalifaxBaseGame_1.1.56.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Target            : {}
LinkType          :
Name              : Microsoft.HalifaxBaseGame_1.1.56.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
FullName          : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.HalifaxBaseGame_1.1.56.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Parent            : WindowsApps
Exists            : True
Root              : C:\
Extension         : .0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
CreationTime      : 2019-09-06 21:44:06
CreationTimeUtc   : 2019-09-06 19:44:06
LastAccessTime    : 2019-09-06 21:44:06
LastAccessTimeUtc : 2019-09-06 19:44:06
LastWriteTime     : 2019-09-06 21:44:06
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 2019-09-06 19:44:06
Attributes        : Directory, ReparsePoint
```

Is it possible that this junctions simply points to "unallocated" space on the partition?

In Windows Event Viewer I see an entry under `Windows Logs/Security` stating `Audit Failure`, `Event ID=5157` for path `\device\harddiskvolume13\geargame\binaries\winstore\gears5.exe` which is a device alias.

Does Windows have kernel support for Store apps? Could it be that the new Gears 5 game gets installed to some virtual partition into which the entry point is the junction `Microsoft.HalifaxBaseGame_1.1.56.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe` from `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` (don't bash, this is new terminology to me)?

## As a reply to @grawity

```
fsutil reparsePoint query .\Microsoft.HalifaxBaseGame_1.1.56.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\
Reparse Tag Value : 0x20000059
Tag value: Name Surrogate
GUID : {924F7678-1E30-4528-9678-0906DC05E06C}

Reparse Data Length: 0x000000a8
Reparse Data:
0000:  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  5b 00 58 00 55 00 43 00  ........[.X.U.C.
0010:  3a 00 5d 00 5c 00 43 00  3a 00 5c 00 50 00 72 00  :.].\.C.:.\.P.r.
0020:  6f 00 67 00 72 00 61 00  6d 00 20 00 46 00 69 00  o.g.r.a.m. .F.i.
0030:  6c 00 65 00 73 00 5c 00  57 00 69 00 6e 00 64 00  l.e.s.\.W.i.n.d.
0040:  6f 00 77 00 73 00 41 00  70 00 70 00 73 00 5c 00  o.w.s.A.p.p.s.\.
0050:  4d 00 53 00 49 00 58 00  56 00 43 00 5c 00 31 00  M.S.I.X.V.C.\.1.
0060:  45 00 36 00 36 00 41 00  33 00 45 00 37 00 2d 00  E.6.6.A.3.E.7.-.
0070:  32 00 46 00 37 00 42 00  2d 00 34 00 36 00 31 00  2.F.7.B.-.4.6.1.
0080:  43 00 2d 00 39 00 46 00  34 00 36 00 2d 00 33 00  C.-.9.F.4.6.-.3.
0090:  45 00 45 00 30 00 41 00  45 00 43 00 36 00 34 00  E.E.0.A.E.C.6.4.
00a0:  42 00 38 00 43 00 00 00                           B.8.C...
```

and if I look at `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MSIXVC\` I see this:
[image: MSIXVC]

which looks very much like a virtual hard disk.

I still don't know how to grant the executable permission through the Windows Firewall though, but this is already great progress.

This is how elevated Process Explorer sees the executable: [image: Gears5.exe image]

and it's spawned with a `dllhost`:
[image: dllhost companion]

Comment: Gears of War 5 is a Win32 application sold on the Windows Store, however, it's still installed in the same location as any other Windows Store application.  What firewall are you using exactly?  I had no problem with Windows Firewall with Gears of War 5.

Comment: Gears of War 5 is indeed installed in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.HalifaxBaseGame_1.1.56.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe`.  If you were to forcefully grant yourself permission to WindowsApps you would be able to confirm this.

Comment: Your current output only says it's a reparse point – but it doesn't actually say it's a junction. What do you get from `fsutil reparsepoint query <path>`? I suspect it's a volume mount point and the app itself is delivered in a .vhdx or similar...

Comment: @grawity I posted a longer response because some formatting is needed. Please post a response as well so I can mark the solution.

Comment: You can (and generally should) edit this information directly into the question post. `MSIXVC` reminds me of a recent article about Microsoft distributing Store games using the Xbox game format (instead of the usual Store appx format), so I can only assume some DRM scheme is involved as well.

Comment: More relevant, I guess, what does _your firewall_ see the paths as? Does it report a full path in logs (or in the "allow this app" dialog if it has one)?

Comment: @grawity I'm blocking outbound. The Windows Firewall has no such dialogs for outbound. I have posted in the initial question what makes it into the Windows Event Log from the firewall - the useless `\device` path.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows firewall has native support for application packages. Application packages are subject to special networking rules.

[image: Firewall rule properties]

Once you created a rule, you can go to its properties and select which application packages it should apply to.

That being said, I’m not sure what you’re trying to accomplish. It’s very unlikely you’d need to manually change firewall settings to allow the game to work.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for Gears 5. Maybe it's because this is a win32 application packaged as an app. I have my firewall set with "block outbound" and I want to whitelist Gears 5.

Comment: @foxX - It certainly worked for me.  I am currently playing Gears of War 5 without a problem.  In reality, without any changes to Windows Firewall, Gears of War 5 works flawlessly.

Comment: @Ramhound What worked?

Comment: @foxX - In reality, I just ran the application, and it automatically was granted access.

Comment: @Ramhound I run the firewall with Block Outbund Connections. Block Outbound Connections is not the default.